# spark-jobserver cannot build on Spark 1.6.2

Tags: apache-spark, spark-jobserver

I'm trying to run the [spark-jobserver 0.6.2](https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver) with Spark 1.6.2

Currently what I'm doing is this:

- git clone https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver.git
- git checkout tags/v0.6.2 -f
- sbt  job-server/package

At this point the system crashes with this error:

```
[info] Compiling 35 Scala sources to /test_jobserver/spark-jobserver/job-server/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[error] 
[error]      while compiling: /test_jobserver/spark-jobserver/job-server/src/spark.jobserver/util/SparkMasterProvider.scala
[error]         during phase: jvm
[error]      library version: version 2.10.6
[error]     compiler version: version 2.10.6
[error]   reconstructed args: -deprecation -classpath /test_jobserver/spark-jobserver/job-server/target/scala-2.10/classes:/test_jobserver/spark-jobserver/akka-app/target/scala-2.10/classes:/test_jobserver/spark-jobserver/job-server-api/target/scala-2.10/classes:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/io.netty/netty-all/jars/netty-all-4.0.29.Final.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe/config/bundles/config-1.3.0.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.akka/akka-cluster_2.10/jars/akka-cluster_2.10-2.3.15.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.akka/akka-remote_2.10/jars/akka-remote_2.10-2.3.15.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.akka/akka-actor_2.10/jars/akka-actor_2.10-2.3.15.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/io.netty/netty/bundles/netty-3.8.0.Final.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/com.google.protobuf/protobuf-java/bundles/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.uncommons.maths/uncommons-maths/jars/uncommons-maths-1.2.2a.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/io.spray/spray-json_2.10/bundles/spray-json_2.10-1.3.2.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/io.spray/spray-can_2.10/bundles/spray-can_2.10-1.3.3.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/io.spray/spray-io_2.10/bundles/spray-io_2.10-1.3.3.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/io.spray/spray-util_2.10/bundles/spray-util_2.10-1.3.3.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/io.spray/spray-http_2.10/bundles/spray-http_2.10-1.3.3.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.parboiled/parboiled-scala_2.10/jars/parboiled-scala_2.10-1.1.7.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.parboiled/parboiled-core/jars/parboiled-core-1.1.7.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/io.spray/spray-caching_2.10/bundles/spray-caching_2.10-1.3.3.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru/jars/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.4.2.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/io.spray/spray-routing_2.10/bundles/spray-routing_2.10-1.3.3.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/io.spray/spray-httpx_2.10/bundles/spray-httpx_2.10-1.3.3.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.jvnet.mimepull/mimepull/jars/mimepull-1.9.5.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/com.chuusai/shapeless_2.10/jars/shapeless_2.10-1.2.4.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/io.spray/spray-client_2.10/bundles/spray-client_2.10-1.3.3.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/com.yammer.metrics/metrics-core/jars/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.joda/joda-convert/jars/joda-convert-1.8.1.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/joda-time/joda-time/jars/joda-time-2.9.3.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.slick/slick_2.10/bundles/slick_2.10-2.1.0.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/com.h2database/h2/jars/h2-1.3.176.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/commons-dbcp/commons-dbcp/jars/commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/commons-pool/commons-pool/jars/commons-pool-1.5.4.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.flywaydb/flyway-core/jars/flyway-core-3.2.1.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.shiro/shiro-core/bundles/shiro-core-1.2.4.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/jars/commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.scoverage/scalac-scoverage-runtime_2.10/jars/scalac-scoverage-runtime_2.10-1.1.1.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.scoverage/scalac-scoverage-plugin_2.10/jars/scalac-scoverage-plugin_2.10-1.1.1.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.10/jars/spark-core_2.10-1.6.1.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.avro/avro-mapred/jars/avro-mapred-1.7.7-hadoop2.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.avro/avro-ipc/jars/avro-ipc-1.7.7-tests.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.avro/avro-ipc/jars/avro-ipc-1.7.7.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.avro/avro/jars/avro-1.7.7.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-core-asl/jars/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/jars/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.xerial.snappy/snappy-java/bundles/snappy-java-1.1.2.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.commons/commons-compress/jars/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.tukaani/xz/jars/xz-1.0.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/jars/slf4j-api-1.7.10.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/com.twitter/chill_2.10/jars/chill_2.10-0.5.0.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/com.twitter/chill-java/jars/chill-java-0.5.0.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/com.esotericsoftware.kryo/kryo/bundles/kryo-2.21.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/com.esotericsoftware.reflectasm/reflectasm/jars/reflectasm-1.07-shaded.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/com.esotericsoftware.minlog/minlog/jars/minlog-1.2.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.objenesis/objenesis/jars/objenesis-1.2.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.xbean/xbean-asm5-shaded/bundles/xbean-asm5-shaded-4.4.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-client/jars/hadoop-client-2.2.0.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-common/jars/hadoop-common-2.2.0.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-annotations/jars/hadoop-annotations-2.2.0.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/com.google.code.findbugs/jsr305/jars/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/commons-cli/commons-cli/jars/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.commons/commons-math/jars/commons-math-2.1.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/xmlenc/xmlenc/jars/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient/jars/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/commons-codec/commons-codec/jars/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/commons-net/commons-net/jars/commons-net-2.2.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/log4j/log4j/bundles/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/commons-lang/commons-lang/jars/commons-lang-2.5.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/commons-configuration/commons-configuration/jars/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/commons-collections/commons-collections/jars/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/commons-digester/commons-digester/jars/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils-core/jars/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-auth/jars/hadoop-auth-2.2.0.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-hdfs/jars/hadoop-hdfs-2.2.0.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.mortbay.jetty/jetty-util/jars/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-app/jars/hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-2.2.0.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-common/jars/hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.2.0.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-yarn-common/jars/hadoop-yarn-common-2.2.0.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-yarn-api/jars/hadoop-yarn-api-2.2.0.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/jars/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/com.google.inject/guice/jars/guice-3.0.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/javax.inject/javax.inject/jars/javax.inject-1.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/aopalliance/aopalliance/jars/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.sonatype.sisu.inject/cglib/jars/cglib-2.2.1-v20090111.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/com.sun.jersey.jersey-test-framework/jersey-test-framework-grizzly2/jars/jersey-test-framework-grizzly2-1.9.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/com.sun.jersey/jersey-server/bundles/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/asm/asm/jars/asm-3.1.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/com.sun.jersey/jersey-json/bundles/jersey-json-1.9.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.codehaus.jettison/jettison/bundles/jettison-1.1.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/stax/stax-api/jars/stax-api-1.0.1.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl/jars/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api/jars/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/javax.activation/activation/jars/activation-1.1.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-jaxrs/jars/jackson-jaxrs-1.8.3.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-xc/jars/jackson-xc-1.8.3.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/com.sun.jersey.contribs/jersey-guice/jars/jersey-guice-1.9.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-yarn-client/jars/hadoop-yarn-client-2.2.0.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/jars/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.2.0.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-yarn-server-common/jars/hadoop-yarn-server-common-2.2.0.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle/jars/hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle-2.2.0.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient/jars/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.2.0.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.spark/spark-launcher_2.10/jars/spark-launcher_2.10-1.6.1.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.spark-project.spark/unused/jars/unused-1.0.0.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.spark/spark-network-common_2.10/jars/spark-network-common_2.10-1.6.1.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.spark/spark-network-shuffle_2.10/jars/spark-network-shuffle_2.10-1.6.1.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.fusesource.leveldbjni/leveldbjni-all/bundles/leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/bundles/jackson-databind-2.4.4.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/bundles/jackson-annotations-2.4.4.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/bundles/jackson-core-2.4.4.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.spark/spark-unsafe_2.10/jars/spark-unsafe_2.10-1.6.1.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/net.java.dev.jets3t/jets3t/jars/jets3t-0.7.1.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.curator/curator-recipes/bundles/curator-recipes-2.4.0.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.curator/curator-framework/bundles/curator-framework-2.4.0.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.curator/curator-client/bundles/curator-client-2.4.0.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.zookeeper/zookeeper/jars/zookeeper-3.4.5.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/jline/jline/jars/jline-0.9.94.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/com.google.guava/guava/bundles/guava-14.0.1.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.eclipse.jetty.orbit/javax.servlet/orbits/javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/jars/commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.commons/commons-math3/jars/commons-math3-3.4.1.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/jars/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.10.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/jars/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.10.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/com.ning/compress-lzf/bundles/compress-lzf-1.0.3.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/net.jpountz.lz4/lz4/jars/lz4-1.3.0.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.roaringbitmap/RoaringBitmap/bundles/RoaringBitmap-0.5.11.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.akka/akka-slf4j_2.10/jars/akka-slf4j_2.10-2.3.11.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.json4s/json4s-jackson_2.10/jars/json4s-jackson_2.10-3.2.10.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.json4s/json4s-core_2.10/jars/json4s-core_2.10-3.2.10.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.json4s/json4s-ast_2.10/jars/json4s-ast_2.10-3.2.10.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/com.thoughtworks.paranamer/paranamer/jars/paranamer-2.6.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scalap/jars/scalap-2.10.0.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-compiler/jars/scala-compiler-2.10.0.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/com.sun.jersey/jersey-core/bundles/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.mesos/mesos/jars/mesos-0.21.1-shaded-protobuf.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/com.clearspring.analytics/stream/jars/stream-2.7.0.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/io.dropwizard.metrics/metrics-core/bundles/metrics-core-3.1.2.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/io.dropwizard.metrics/metrics-jvm/bundles/metrics-jvm-3.1.2.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/io.dropwizard.metrics/metrics-json/bundles/metrics-json-3.1.2.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/io.dropwizard.metrics/metrics-graphite/bundles/metrics-graphite-3.1.2.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/com.fasterxml.jackson.module/jackson-module-scala_2.10/bundles/jackson-module-scala_2.10-2.4.4.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-reflect/jars/scala-reflect-2.10.4.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.ivy/ivy/jars/ivy-2.4.0.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/oro/oro/jars/oro-2.0.8.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.tachyonproject/tachyon-client/jars/tachyon-client-0.8.2.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/commons-io/commons-io/jars/commons-io-2.4.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.tachyonproject/tachyon-underfs-hdfs/jars/tachyon-underfs-hdfs-0.8.2.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.tachyonproject/tachyon-underfs-s3/jars/tachyon-underfs-s3-0.8.2.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/org.tachyonproject/tachyon-underfs-local/jars/tachyon-underfs-local-0.8.2.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/net.razorvine/pyrolite/jars/pyrolite-4.9.jar:/home/marco/.ivy2/cache/net.sf.py4j/py4j/jars/py4j-0.9.jar -feature -bootclasspath /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/classes:/home/marco/.sbt/boot/scala-2.10.6/lib/scala-library.jar -language:implicitConversions -language:postfixOps
[error] 
[error]   last tree to typer: Literal(Constant(collection.Set))
[error]               symbol: null
[error]    symbol definition: null
[error]                  tpe: Class(classOf[scala.collection.Set])
[error]        symbol owners: 
[error]       context owners: object DefaultSparkMasterProvider -> package util
[error] 
[error] == Enclosing template or block ==
[error] 
[error] Template( // val <local DefaultSparkMasterProvider>: <notype> in object DefaultSparkMasterProvider, tree.tpe=spark.jobserver.util.DefaultSparkMasterProvider.type
[error]   "java.lang.Object", "spark.jobserver.util.SparkMasterProvider" // parents
[error]   ValDef(
[error]     private
[error]     "_"
[error]     <tpt>
[error]     <empty>
[error]   )
[error]   // 2 statements
[error]   DefDef( // def getSparkMaster(config: com.typesafe.config.Config): String in object DefaultSparkMasterProvider
[error]     <method>
[error]     "getSparkMaster"
[error]     []
[error]     // 1 parameter list
[error]     ValDef( // config: com.typesafe.config.Config
[error]       <param> <triedcooking>
[error]       "config"
[error]       <tpt> // tree.tpe=com.typesafe.config.Config
[error]       <empty>
[error]     )
[error]     <tpt> // tree.tpe=String
[error]     Apply( // def getString(x$1: String): String in trait Config, tree.tpe=String
[error]       "config"."getString" // def getString(x$1: String): String in trait Config, tree.tpe=(x$1: String)String
[error]       "spark.master"
[error]     )
[error]   )
[error]   DefDef( // def <init>(): spark.jobserver.util.DefaultSparkMasterProvider.type in object DefaultSparkMasterProvider
[error]     <method>
[error]     "<init>"
[error]     []
[error]     List(Nil)
[error]     <tpt> // tree.tpe=spark.jobserver.util.DefaultSparkMasterProvider.type
[error]     Block( // tree.tpe=Unit
[error]       Apply( // def <init>(): Object in class Object, tree.tpe=Object
[error]         DefaultSparkMasterProvider.super."<init>" // def <init>(): Object in class Object, tree.tpe=()Object
[error]         Nil
[error]       )
[error]       ()
[error]     )
[error]   )
[error] )
[error] 
[error] == Expanded type of tree ==
[error] 
[error] ConstantType(value = Constant(collection.Set))
[error] 
[error] uncaught exception during compilation: java.io.IOException
[error] File name too long
[error] two errors found
[error] (job-server/compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 16 s, completed Oct 25, 2016 3:32:36 PM
```

I didn't find anything, somebody knows how to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, you can't run this on an encrypted folder on Ubuntu.

Moving the project folder to a disk partition *non- encrypted* made the magic.

For more infos, see: https://github.com/scala/pickling/issues/10